# gvm installation error on debian vps

Tags: linux, git, bash, curl, gcc

```
root@Aaron:~# sudo apt-get install curl git mercurial make binutils bison gcc build-essential -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
binutils is already the newest version.
bison is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
make is already the newest version.
mercurial is already the newest version.
git is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

root@Aaron:~# bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)
ERROR: Already installed!

root@Aaron:~# gvm install go1.4
Already installed!

root@Aaron:~# gvm use go1.4 [--default]
Now using version go1.4

root@Aaron:~# gvm install go1.4 -B
Already installed!

root@Aaron:~# gvm use go1.4
Now using version go1.4

root@Aaron:~# export GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$GOROOT

root@Aaron:~# gvm install go1.5
Installing go1.5...
 * Compiling...
ERROR: Failed to compile. Check the logs at /root/.gvm/logs/go-go1.5-compile.log
ERROR: Failed to use installed version
```

I have tried to do this multiple times, on three different linux vps and they all give the same error. My current go version is go1.4 linux/amd64. I've tried reinstalling and that hasn't worked either.

The output for compile log is

Building Go bootstrap tool.

cmd/dist

Building Go toolchain using /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4.

bootstrap/internal/obj
bootstrap/internal/obj/arm
bootstrap/internal/obj/arm64
bootstrap/internal/obj/ppc64
bootstrap/internal/obj/x86
bootstrap/asm/internal/arch
bootstrap/asm/internal/flags
bootstrap/asm/internal/lex
bootstrap/asm/internal/asm
bootstrap/asm
bootstrap/compile/internal/big
bootstrap/internal/gcprog
bootstrap/compile/internal/gc
go build bootstrap/compile/internal/gc: /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g: signal: killed
bootstrap/link/internal/ld
bootstrap/link/internal/amd64
bootstrap/link/internal/arm
bootstrap/link/internal/arm64
bootstrap/link/internal/ppc64
bootstrap/link/internal/x86
bootstrap/link
go tool dist: FAILED: /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4/bin/go install -v bootstrap/...: exit status 1

Comment: Well what is in `/root/.gvm/logs/go-go1.5-compile.log` ?

Comment: # Building Go toolchain using /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4. boo bootstrap/internal/obj/arm64 bootstrap/internal/obj/ppc64 bootstrap/compile/internal/big bootstrap/internal/gcprog bootstrap/compile/internal/gc go build bootstrap/compile/internal/gc: /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g: signal: killed bootstrap/link/internal/ld bootstrap/link/internal/amd64 bootstrap/link/internal/arm bootstrap/link/internal/arm64 bootstrap/link/internal/ppc64 bootstrap/link/internal/x86 bootstrap/link go tool dist: FAILED: /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4/bin/go install -v bootstrap/...: exit status 1

Comment: As you can see, comments is not a good place for long texts. Edit your question and add this text in there.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks weird:

```
bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)
```

Try:

```
bash <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)
```

And note that, by doing it this way, you are trusting `moovweb` to execute whatever instructions they put in that script.

If this doesn't work, the command tells you to look at `/root/.gvm/logs/go-go1.5-compile.log`. Is there anything important there?

Comment: ##### Building Go toolchain using /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4.
boo
bootstrap/internal/obj/arm64
bootstrap/internal/obj/ppc64
bootstrap/compile/internal/big
bootstrap/internal/gcprog
bootstrap/compile/internal/gc
go build bootstrap/compile/internal/gc: /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6g: signal: killed
bootstrap/link/internal/ld
bootstrap/link/internal/amd64
bootstrap/link/internal/arm
bootstrap/link/internal/arm64
bootstrap/link/internal/ppc64
bootstrap/link/internal/x86
bootstrap/link
go tool dist: FAILED: /root/.gvm/gos/go1.4/bin/go install -v bootstrap/...: exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, I had the same troubles myself.

Note if you get the error: *-bash: gvm: command not found*

Run:

> source /Users/macbook/.gvm/scripts/gvm

You reached the first two lines below, follow up with the rest:

> gvm install go1.4
>
> gvm use go1.4
>
> export GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$GOROOT
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
>
> PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
>
> gvm use go1.4
>
> set -x GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP GOROOTset -x GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP GOROOT

Then view the latest version available and install the one you want

> gvm listall
>
> gvm install go1.8.3 -B
>
> gvm use go1.8.3

Check your versions

> gvm list